# Problem with ^^<HEX>

Tags: macros, errors, tex-core, expansion

I have small problem with `^^<HEX>`.

If I have a `<HEX>` part of the `^^<HEX>` in the macro `\def\attemp{<HEX>}`, I cannot write `^^<HEX>` as

1. `^^\attempt` or
2. `\edef\attemptB{\noexpand^\noexpand^\attempt}`.

Because:

1. TeX evaluates `^^\attempt` like `{^^\}attempt`...
2. Tex will recognize `^` as superscript character and prints `"! Missing $ inserted."`

My working solution is:

```
\def\asciitochar#1{%  
\def\attemp{#1}%  
\def\att{\noexpand^\noexpand^\attempt\noexpand\endinput} % produce ^^#1\endinput%  
\immediate\openout\mywrite=\noexpand^\noexpand^\attempt.gen.tex%  
\immediate\write\mywrite{\att}%  
\immediate\closeout\mywrite%  
%  
\input \noexpand^\noexpand^\attempt.gen.tex%  
}
```

but solution above is not 'clean' (I think :)).

Has someone solution without creating temporary files...?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to do (the broader context)? The `^^<number>` notation is there to allow input of non-standard chars: usually, you'd not try to give the number without the `^^` part.

Comment: I want to convert ASCII code to char. Example i have HEX ascii code 41 (large A --> ^^41). But my ASCII code is in the macro \def\atempt{41}....

Comment: Rather than `\noexpand` you have to use `\expandafter`

Comment: `\expandafter` not work because `^^<HEX>` is evaluated bafere macro expansion. `\expandafter^^\attemp` bahaves like `{^^\}attempt` and `\expandafter^\expandafter^\attempt` "behaves as superscript." (in PlainTeX)

Comment: what do you want to do with the character really? The answers including mine generate the character _token_ but if you just want to typeset the character you don't need that you can use `\def\asciitochar#1{\char"#1 }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TeX does the `^^<number>` to char conversion very 'early', and it has to happen during tokenization. Traditional TeX does not give you a good way around the problem posed: you have to write to file and read back. In plain TeX I'd do that as

```
\newwrite\mywrite
\catcode`\@=11 %
\def\asciitochar#1{%
  \def\ascii{#1}%
  \begingroup
    \toks@\expandafter{\expandafter^\expandafter^\ascii}%
    \immediate\openout\mywrite=\jobname.txt %
    \immediate\write\mywrite{\the\toks@}%
    \immediate\closeout\mywrite
  \endgroup
  \input\jobname.txt %
}
\asciitochar{41}
\bye
```

With e-TeX available, you can use `\scantokens` instead

```
\def\asciitochar#1{%
  \def\ascii{#1}%
  \scantokens\expandafter{\expandafter^\expandafter^\ascii}%
}
\asciitochar{41}
\bye
```

(You don't say in the question, but presumably in the real case the number is already stored as a macro before you get it, otherwise you'd use it directly.)

Answer (score 6):

The `^^` notation works only during tokenization, so well before macro expansion takes place.

If you want that `\asciitochar{41}` writes `A` in the file `A.gen.tex` you can do like this:

```
\newwrite\mywrite

\begingroup\catcode`\^^@=12 % ^^@ has usually category code 9
  \def\x{\endgroup
    \def\asciitochar##1{%
      \begingroup
      \lccode`\^^@="##1\relax
      \lowercase{\endgroup
        \immediate\openout\mywrite=^^@.gen.tex
        \immediate\write\mywrite{^^@\noexpand\endinput}%
        \immediate\closeout\mywrite
        \input ^^@.gen.tex
      }
    }
  }\x

\asciitochar{41}

\bye
```

With `\lowercase` and the setting of `` \lccode`\^^@="#1 `` you transform every `^^@` into the real character with ASCII code `#1` (in hexadecimal).

Answer (score 6):

```
\def\asciitochar#1{%  
\begingroup
\uccode`a="#1\relax
\uppercase{\endgroup\input a}.tex }


\asciitochar{41}


\asciitochar{42}



\bye
```

will input A.tex then B.tex:

```
$ pdftex zz44
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./zz44.tex (./A.tex) (./B.tex) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on zz44.log.
```